# Gröbner/SAGBI bases for non-commutative setting

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, rt.representation-theory

It is well known that SAGBI/Gröbner bases are important for commutative and non-commutative algebra. The references for commutative scenery is ample and vast, but I am in trouble to find a good reference for the general theory of SAGBI/Gröbner bases for non-commutative setting. Actually, I am interesting in the following subjects:

(1) Where can I find the general construction of these bases for non-commutative setting?

(2) Is there some reference for the specific case of the Universal enveloping algebra of a finite-dimensional  semi-simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$?

(3) Does exist a reference using this bases in representation theory? For instance, in the study of universal objects defined by generators and relations.

THANKS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the non-commutative situation, it is called Groebner-Shirshov basis. See, for example, the survey paper "[Groebner-Shirshov Bases: Some New Results](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1344)" by L. A. Bokut and Yuqun Chen, and references there. The case of universal enveloping algebra was considered by Bergman in G. M. Bergman, [The diamond lemma for ring theory](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90010-5), Adv. in Math., 29, 178-218 (1978). I do not know about representation theory, but certainly this is one of the main tools of studying finitely presented rings and algebras over a field. The problem, of course, is that a finite Groebner-Shirshov basis (unlike Groebner basis in the commutative case) does not always exist.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of papers dealing with representation-theoretic questions and universal enveloping algebras using Gröbner bases. Some examples are given by these: [1](https://s-space.snu.ac.kr/bitstream/10371/12179/1/42.pdf), [2](https://doi.org/10.1090/S1061-0022-2011-01159-8), [3](http://www.springerlink.com/content/bwn7336156456u7u/), [4](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218196796000234).

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 2):

You should be interested in the discussion in

*Evans, Gareth A.; Wensley, Christopher D.*, [**Complete involutive rewriting systems**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2007.07.005), J. Symb. Comput. 42, No. 11-12, 1034-1051 (2007). [ZBL1128.68044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1128.68044).

on the notion of noncommutative involutive systems, which in the commutative case are a well known modification of the Gröbner basis theory. Evans' thesis is available at [math.RA/0602140](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602140).

I can't help on the proposed applications.

Ronnie Brown